How To Tell My MMO Hash Function Code Is Correct
I want to appreciate any feedback you can provide in advance.
My current code is the following, written in Python:
def g(H):
    if H[-1] == '0':
        H = H[:-2] + '11'
    return H

def MMO_hash(plaintextFileName, hashedValueFileName, outputFileName):
    with open(plaintextFileName, 'r') as f:
        plaintext = f.read()

    with open(hashedValueFileName, 'r') as f:
        H0 = f.read()

    H = H0
    
    chunks = [bin(ord(char))[2:].zfill(6) for char in plaintext]

    for i, chunk in enumerate(chunks):
        k = int(g(H),2)

        x = int(chunk, 2)

        new_value = (k*x) % 64

        H = bin(new_value ^ x) [2:].zfill(6)

    hash_value = H

    with open(outputFileName, 'w') as f:
        f.write(hash_value)

    return hash_value

plaintextFileName = 'plaintext.txt'
H0 = 'hashvalue.txt'
output = 'output.txt'
hashedValue = MMO_hash(plaintextFileName, H0, output)
print ("Hashed Value:", hashedValue)

////////////////////////////////
The plaintext that I used is the following:
I have two pet cats. One is an orange and cream Maine Coon named Oliver and the other is a Tuxedo named Tux.
The hash value I used is 110011
The output I received is 000000
////////////////////////////////////
The assignment:
Consider the Matyas-Meyer-Oseas hash function presented in the textbook 1, and also in the
Module 7 notes2. You should implement a 128-bit version of this hash function.
Recall that the input x to the hash function has arbitrary length, the key k for the hash function
is an odd integer between 1 and 2**128-1, and that we encrypt a 128-bit block via multiplication
by k modulo 2128. Finally, recall that k is replaced by the function g that derives the key.
Assume the inputs to your code are a plaintext file name, and a hash value file name. You must
provide the following:

The method MMO_hash(plaintextFileName, hashedValueFileName) that hashes the
text in the file named by the first parameter into the 128-bit message digest that is
written to the file named in the second parameter.

////////////////////////////////////////
The issue:
I am unsure where my code is breaking down. I wrote down what steps that need to happen -
Steps that need to happen

The plain text needs to be broken up into bits of 6 with left padding if necessary. They should be assigned a variable such as X1, X2, X3, etc.
You then take H0, which should be provided, and perform the g function. In this case the g function will look at the last bit. If it’s 0 it’ll change the last two bits into 1s. If it is 1 nothing changes.
This new bit will then become k. You will convert k to an integer
You will now that that first chunk on the left, x1, and convert it to a number. You will then multiply the integer you got for k with the integer for x1 then use mod 64 to get your new value, which you will convert to binary.
Next you will take that new value and XOR it to the initial value of x1. This will then give you the value of h1.
You will then follow the same steps except you will replace the H0 with the H1 for this. You’ll continue doing this until you finish with the last chunk of binary code. That final h value will be your encrypted h(x).

I just need assistance seeing what I'm doing wrong. We do have to write this from scratch so we can't use libraries.
///////////////////////////
So I keep running different hash values and I'm always receiving the answer 000000

I just noticed that I was cutting it into 6 bit segments instead of 128 bit segments and that the initial hash value had to be changed. Still, is there an easy way to verify that the output is correct? Perhaps a website that can be used where I can enter the plain text and hash value to see if the output matches my code? I've been trying to find something like that and so far I haven't found a good website to use.
